# Papa Parse worker configuration?

Tags: javascript, csv, frontend, worker, papaparse

I'm using Papa Parse to read a large file (100k+ lines, and takes a couple of seconds to process). I'm following the [documentation](https://www.papaparse.com).

**1st attempt:** Getting CSV from a URL, wait till it finishes, then do work. **Works perfectly.** No problems at all. Is slow though.

```
Papa.parse(url, {
    download: true,
    complete: function() {
        console.log("All done!");
    }
});
```

**2nd attempt:** Getting CSV from a URL, work on it line-by-line. **Works perfectly.** No problems at all. Is still slow, of course.

```
Papa.parse(url, {
    download: true,
    step: function() {
        console.log("123...");
    }
    complete: function() {
        console.log("All done!");
    }
});
```

**3rd attempt:** Getting CSV from a URL, work on it line-by-line. Uses `worker` to make it not freeze. **Does not work at all.**

```
Papa.parse(url, {
    download: true,
    worker: true,
    step: function() {
        console.log("123...");
    }
    complete: function() {
        console.log("All done!");
    }
});
```

Without `worker: true`, everything works as expected. With `worker: true`, regardless if we use just `step`, just `complete`, or both, it stops working.

Firefox gives no error message. Chrome will say `null`, which is better than nothing, but does not say what is `null`.

Not sure what the problem is or how to fix it from here. Any advice would be appreciated.